# How to unbox the data type?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code snippet:

```
newtype SomeType = SomeType [(Int,Double)]
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

My function accept `SomeType`. How to iterate over each element of list?

Comment: What do you need to do while iterating over this list?

Comment: @Jefffrey, I have function `Int -> Char`. I want to apply this function to each int in `SomeType`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether `SomeType` is declared as `data` or `newtype`, the procedure is the same: you just pattern-match against it.

```
my_function (SomeType list) = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to iterate each element of the list. Apart from @MathematicalOrchid's answer, one another way would be to do this is by introducing an unwrapper function and using that:

```
newtype SomeType = SomeType { getSomeType :: [(Int,Double)] } 
  deriving (Eq,Show)

myFunction :: SomeType -> SomeType
myFunction xs = SomeType $ map (\(x,y) -> (x*2,y)) (getSomeType xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your type definition, data constructor `SomeType` (the right one) can be used in pattern matching to extract fields of that type, so in `foo (SomeType st) = ...`, `st` will be a list of type `[(Int, Double)]`.